# CPU Locks up due to intel sound drivers during boot

Tags: drivers, sound, startup, udev

My Vivid Vevet install was working just fine until I did an update. On the next startup the screen would just freeze on the loading screen before I could decrypt the hard drive. I can't get to recovery mode and using older kernels does not solve the issue. The error is

> Warning: CPU: 3 PID: 0 at /build/buildd/linux-3.19.0/kernel/watchdog.c:290 watchdog_overflow_callback+0x92/0xc0()
>   Modules linked in: snd_hda_intel(OE+) snd_hda_codec(OE) snd_hda_core(OE)

UPDATE: I just tried restarting again and I was able to see that the udev kernel manager fails to start (could not see it before as the text moved too fast the other times)

Comment: Try using a LiveUSB. Go the live desktop and open the  install ubuntu on the desktop. From  there, try to click "upgrade on the install screen when/if it finds the prev. Ubuntu.It will try to install again.

Comment: Is there an easy way to do that from the a gparted live usb as I have one of those on hand at the moment.

Comment: sure in the install you can flash the hard disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1460933#p1460933 in the comments of the bug.

I had to modify add

> options snd-hda-intel enable=0,1,0

Somewhere in my /etc/modprobe.d, I chose to put it in my Alsa.conf because that seemed to make sense.

Beyond that the best I can tell as to what happened to the driver was that something at boot was making it look like the soundcard was being hotswapped and then the driver freaked out and started locking up the CPU.