# Ubuntu 16.04 installation on laptop just won't work

Tags: boot, 16.04

I have tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 on an (older) laptop (ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso) via USB stick. The installation itself worked fine, and a reboot of the system works too. The login screen comes up, you can log in, everything is fine.

But when booted a second time, the following text briefly appears on the screen:

```
A TPM error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr.
```

Then more text appear on the screen and looks like follows:

```
[  13.27323] [<ffffffffff81b46272>] watchdog_overflow_callback+0xdb/0xd0
[  13.27323] [<ffffffffff81b46e4c>] perf_event_overflow_+...
```

(I had to type the whole page by hand, so I put only two lines. Ask me if you need something more specific).

I tried to re-install ubuntu, but run into the exact same issue.

Anything I could try? I did a harddisk and memory test before installation, which passed without problems. The laptop is a Compaq 8510w with 4GB RAM and an Intel Core 2 2400 MHz CPU.

Comment: This might help http://askubuntu.com/questions/629383/cpu-locks-up-due-to-intel-sound-drivers-during-boot

Comment: Now the question of how to fix that without re-installing ubuntu again. Also, I get many many lines of errors. Those I posted are just random examples

Comment: Personally, I would try redownloading the ISO and burning it again.

Comment: How often? 5 times? 10 times? 100 times?

Comment: How often? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Try adding `acpi=off` to the kernel boot parameter in `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: Can I do that in the Boot Setup somewhere? I don't see anything related to ACPI in there unfortunately

Comment: I downloaded the iso image again. Exact same md5sum. So its the exact same file. No need to repeat the installation with the exact same iso...

Comment: @Alex boot into rescue mode (hit `shift` immediately after the startup screen goes blank to get to the grub menu and then hit `c` to drop to a root shell).

Comment: @Alex enter `nano /etc/default/grub` Find the line that reads `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and add `acpi=off`. The end result should look like this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"`

Comment: Neither vi nor nano installed it seems...

Comment: @Alex exit with `ctrl-X` and then enter `update-grub`. When that's finished, reboot and see what happens.

Comment: "Neither vi nor nano installed it seems..." that's impossible, the base install comes with vi and nano

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42024/discussion-between-alex-and-alcuin-arundel).

Comment: On the grub command line (starting with `grub>`) it says: `error: can't find command 'vi'.`

Comment: @Alex Try typing `vim` instead, it should be installed